# query for getting columns names of table provided having values in sqlite

Tags: ios, mysql, objective-c, sqlite

i'm, the developing a dictionary app in objective c...and i also have database of it, the description TABLE in Database contains all data related to a word definition

```
_id  
definition  
category  
synonyms  
hyponyms  
instanceHyponyms  
hypernyms  
instanceHypernyms  
partHolonyms  
memberHolonyms  
substanceHolonyms  
partMeronyms  
memberMeronyms  
substanceMeronyms  
bla bla bla
```

but for some words some columns have values and other have not..
i want to retrieve only those columns having values ( both , names and also their values) ...  it will be good if id column is skipped

Answer (score 0):

Just write:

```
SELECT * from tablename where hypernyms IS NOT NULL AND instanceHypernyms IS NOT NULL;
```

append those fields in this query along with `AND` which value can be null.